# i18n not working in Yii user-defined components

Tags: php, yii, internationalization, translation

I created a simple component in my Yii project and there is a text on it that needs to be translated using i18n feature of Yii

```
class MySimpleComponent{
   public static function WelcomeCurrentUser(){
       $wuser = Yii::t("lstrings","Welcome back ");
       $wuser .= Yii::app()->session['curuser']; 
       return $wuser;
   }
}
```

I invoke that small component function in one of my views.

```
echo MySimpleComponent::WelcomeCurrentUser();
```

but as i change the language in one of my controllers using the following code

```
Yii::app()->language = 'ja' //change language to japanese
```

the translation doesn't work... I double check my i18n strings to ensure that messages are exact to each other  and still doesn't work.

this is my lstrings.php file

```
return array("Hello"=>"こんにちは",
             "Welcome back "=>"お帰りなさい",
);
```

Any ideas why the translation does not work? any solutions? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
Yii::app()->language = 'ja'
```

before

```
echo MySimpleComponent::WelcomeCurrentUser();
```

Language translate will take effect as long as before Yii::t()

Comment: It can also be setup in the **protected/config/main.php**
`'sourceLanguage' => 'en_us',`
`'language' => 'ja_jp',`
But that's more of a default for the whole app.